# Moving ball collision with non-movable ball in C++ & SFML

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml, game-development

So, basically I am trying to implement **basic gravity simulator in C++ using SFML**, and that works, but I have a problem with collision. There is a **planet(gravity source) - non-movable ball**, that doesn't have any velocity, doesn't change its position, **its fixed**, and we have **particle - movable ball that reacts to the gravity source**. At some point those two balls will collide and I am trying to **calculate properly new velocity vector - after collision, for particle** (gravity source doesn't move!), but whatever I do it's just not what I want to achieve.

Thanks for all that will be kind to help me with this problem!

Here is the method I created so far:

```
void updatePhysics(GravitySource& gravitySource, float deltaTime)
    {
        //Normal Vector
        float distanceX = gravitySource.getPos().x - pos.x;
        float distanceY = gravitySource.getPos().y - pos.y;

        //Distance between GravitySource and Particle
        float distance = std::sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

        //Simplifying division to speed up calculations
        float inverseDistance = 1.f / distance;

        //Unit Vector
        float normalizedX = inverseDistance * distanceX;
        float normalizedY = inverseDistance * distanceY;

        float inverseSquareDropOff = inverseDistance * inverseDistance;

        //Calculating Acceleration
        float accelerationX = normalizedX * gravitySource.getStrength() * inverseSquareDropOff * deltaTime;
        float accelerationY = normalizedY * gravitySource.getStrength() * inverseSquareDropOff * deltaTime;

        //Updating Velocity
        vel.x += accelerationX;
        vel.y += accelerationY;

        //Updating Position
        pos.x += vel.x;
        pos.y += vel.y;

        //Updating Render Position
        relPos.x = pos.x - radius;
        relPos.y = pos.y - radius;

        //TODO: Make collision work properly!!!
        //Checking for collision
        if (distance <= radius + gravitySource.getRadius())
        {
            //Tangent Vector
            float tangentX = -normalizedY;
            float tangentY = normalizedX;

            //Velocity scalar in normal direction
            float normalScalarX = normalizedX * vel.x;
            float normalScalarY = normalizedY * vel.y;

            //New Unit Vector
            normalizedX = normalScalarX * normalizedX;
            normalizedY = normalScalarY * normalizedY;

            std::cout << vel.x << " " << vel.y << std::endl;
            vel.x = normalizedX + tangentX;
            vel.y = normalizedY + tangentY;
            std::cout << vel.x << " " << vel.y << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

```
class GravitySource
{
    sf::Vector2f pos;
    sf::Vector2f relPos;
    float strength;
    float radius;
    sf::CircleShape circleShape;
};
```

```
class Particle
{
    sf::Vector2f pos;
    sf::Vector2f relPos;
    sf::Vector2f vel;
    float radius;
    sf::CircleShape circleShape;
};
```

Comment: You may find this useful: [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/pool-hall-lessons-fast-accurate-collision-detection-between-circles-or-spheres)

Comment: You want to find a vector projection **p** of your velocity vector **v** onto the line that connects the centres, then **v'** = **v** - 2**p**. The projection can be found as **p** = (**v·rₙ**) **rₙ** where **rₙ** is the normalised (unit-length) vector between the centres.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI You are my HERO!!! That works! Thank you a lot, wow that is amazing, but I am heading up to learn more about vectors!

Answer (score 1):

Lennard-Jones Potential is an easy way of applying a smooth push+pull interaction:

[image]

```
    struct Particle
    {
        float x, y, vx, vy;
        bool movable;
        float fx, fy;
        Particle(float xP, float yP, float vxP, float vyP, bool mP)
        {
            x = xP;
            y = yP;
            vx = vxP;
            vy = vyP;
            movable = mP;
            fx = 0;
            fy = 0;
        }

        void ResetForce() { fx = 0; fy = 0; }

        void InteractionForce(Particle & p)
        {
            float dx = x - p.x;
            float dy = y - p.y;
            float r = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            float gravitationPuller = r * r * r;
            float gravitationPusher = r * r * r * r;
            float fx0 = dx / gravitationPuller;
            float fy0 = dy / gravitationPuller;
            float fx1 = 100.0f*dx / gravitationPusher;
            float fy1 = 100.0f * dy / gravitationPusher;
            p.fx += fx0 - fx1;
            p.fy += fy0 - fy1;
            fx -= fx0 - fx1;
            fy -= fy0 - fy1;
        }

        void MoveEuler(float dt)
        {
            if (movable)
            {
                x += vx * dt;
                y += vy * dt;
                vx += fx * dt;
                vy += fy * dt;
            }
        }

    };

    cv::namedWindow("test");
    cv::Mat img0(800, 600, CV_32FC3);
    img0 = 0;
    std::vector<Particle> particles;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        particles.emplace_back((i % 3)*100 + i*40, (i / 3)*100, 0, 0, i != 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        cv::Mat img = img0.clone();
        for (int j = 0; j < particles.size(); j++)
            particles[j].ResetForce();

        for (int j = 0; j < particles.size()-1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < particles.size(); k++)
            {
                particles[j].InteractionForce(particles[k]);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < particles.size(); j++)
            particles[j].MoveEuler(5.0f);

        for (int j = 0; j < particles.size(); j++)
        {
            if(particles[j].movable)
                cv::circle(img, cv::Point2f(particles[j].x, particles[j].y), 20, cv::Scalar(50, 100, 150),cv::FILLED);
            else
                cv::circle(img, cv::Point2f(particles[j].x, particles[j].y), 30, cv::Scalar(250, 100, 150), cv::FILLED);
        }

        cv::imshow("test", img.clone());
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
```

Comment: Well that is not quite what I needed. You gave me push + pull interaction, but I have pull interaction from gravity source and I need to calculate new velocity vector after particle collision with this gravity source - the problem is that they both are circles and I don't know how to calculate velocity after collision.

Comment: If you dont want velocity, then use verlet integration. It only computes position and force.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out with help of the @n.m.couldbeanAI and the code looks like that(rest of this function you have in the question):

```
    //Checking for collision
    if (distance <= radius + gravitySource.getRadius())
    {
        //Projection Vector
        float projectionX = (vel.x * normalizedX + vel.y * normalizedY) * normalizedX;
        float projectionY = (vel.x * normalizedX + vel.y * normalizedY) * normalizedY;

        //Calculating new Velocity Vector
        vel.x = vel.x - 2 * projectionX;
        vel.y = vel.y - 2 * projectionY;
    }
```

Thank you all for help!